# Verify if relation was saved or deleted

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I would like to check if a relation was saved directly into the controller.  But currently I cannot find the solution

My code :

```
@ut = UsersTask.where(task_id: @task.id).where(user_id: @user.id).delete_all
if @ut.destroyed?
  @task.update(effectif: (@task.effectif -= 1))
end
```

Comment: Is `effectif` supposed to be a count of tasks?  You could just do `@task.users_tasks.count` or (if it's specific to a user) `@task.users_tasks.where(user: @user).count`

Comment: Thanks @SteveTurczyn bu it's a really heavy request, so I would like to avoid it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make something like that :

```
respond_to do |format|
  if @task.users.include?(@user)
    format.js {render inline: "location.reload();" }
  else
    UsersTask.where(task_id: @task.id, user_id: @user.id).first_or_create
    @task.update(effectif: (@task.effectif += 1))
    format.js 
  end
end
```

Comment: Great solution @jacquesMesnet, it's a really cool and elegant solution for my case !! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`delete_all` returns a number of affected rows. I think it will be enough to compare `@ut.count` with the return of `delete_all`. Simply assign those two values to variables and compare them:

```
@ut = UsersTask.where(task_id: @task.id).where(user_id: @user.id)
@tasks_to_delete = @ut.size
@deleted_tasks = @ut.delete_all

if @tasks_to_delete.eql?(@deleted_tasks)
  @task.update(effectif: (@task.effectif -= 1))
end
```

Or, if you do not want to load `UsersTasks` into `@ut`, you can do:

```
users_task_number = UsersTask.count
@ut = UsersTask.where(task_id: @task.id).where(user_id: @user.id).delete_all
if UsersTask.count.eql?(users_task_number - @ut)
  @task.update(effectif: (@task.effectif -= 1))
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @MrShemek, it looks a good solution to solve it